# iOS add imageView to scrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6e13.png)When i add three imageViews to scrollView, and i setting scrollView contentSize is three times scrollView's width, even if it was appeared in  scrolView,but imageView's width not equal to scrollview's. I ensured that already setting they width equeal to each otehr. If who know that how to resolve this issue,please help me, thinks.

```
- (void)addScrollViewImage {
for (NSInteger index = 0; index < IMAGE_NUM; index++) {
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    CGFloat imageViewX = index * (self.scrollView.frame.size.width);
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(imageViewX, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width , self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"搜索图片"];
    imageView.contentMode =  UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
}
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * IMAGE_NUM, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

}

Comment: is `autolayout` enabled in your project ?

Comment: Are you using constraints?

Comment: Where "addScrollViewImage" method get called? In viewDidLoad()? Try to call in viewDidApprear(), where you will get the actual scrollview width.

Comment: yes ,i used Autolayout  in my project. But only setting scrollview's constraints,imageview by addScrollViewImage: this function  add.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change imageview content mode

```
imageView.contentMode =  UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

With

```
imageView.contentMode =  UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

Comment: But i changed imageView's contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill, this problem exists too. I don't know that i have already setted it's correct  orginX ,but there is a gap between imageView and scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when your viewController is loaded, view / scrollView frame is still unknown.

You need to override *viewDidLayoutSubviews()* and **setup children frames** and **content size** there.

**Important note**: iOS is adding **EXTRA** UIImageView's for scroll indicators. That's why you can't use **scrollView.subviews.count** inside viewDidLayoutSubviews(), but you can use IMAGE_NUM though.

Some Swift code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let scrollSize = scrollView.bounds.size
    var frame = scrollView.bounds

    // Wrong: for i in 0 ..< scrollView.subviews.count
    for i in 0 ..< IMAGE_NUM {
        let view = scrollView.subviews[i]
        view.frame = frame
        frame.origin.x += scrollSize.width
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: frame.origin.x, height: scrollSize.height)
}
```